# How to map a call debug name to transpiled C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, transpiler

Does C++ allow attaching names to functions for debugging? The `#line` directive seems to solve the file name and line. With the following code:

```
#include <cassert>

namespace com::q {
    struct C {
        #line 404 "index.vs"
        static void f() {
            assert(false);
        }
    };
}

int main() {
#line 777 "index.vs"
    com::q::C::f();
}
```

I get:

> index.vs:405: static void com::q::C::f(int): Assertion `false' failed.

Which is almost what I want.

Is it possible to:

- Erase the signature and display only the fully-qualified function name?
- Is there something like the following?

```
#debugfunction com.q.C.f
```

Comment: One simple hack that can get you a bit closer is to embed a string in the `assert` condition. Eg: `assert(("here I am!", false));`. If you can pop in the `__func__` macro, you're even closer.

Comment: Mind you, I just remembered this lil' addition to C++20: [`std::source_location::function_name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/function_name) that obsoletes `__func__` and its implementation-specific brethren.

Comment: There are the `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` macros that you can use as strings. But usually decorating your code with debug statements makes it differ from procuction code which is also not what you should want. Can't you just use a debugger?

Comment: Agreed ^. Once spent a couple weeks proving that two sets of line-macro infested code were truly compiling to identical binaries.

Comment: @user4581301 the famous, lets be lazy and put a function call in an assert comes to mind too ;)

Comment: The same is true for too much logging, my advise keep all the debug/trace/assert stuff out of your code and design it to be unit testable. Then use unit tests and the debugger to get the problems out (of small parts) before integrating into bigger units. You get much more readble and cleaner code and you know it works.